# MYSQL joining to empty temp table is very slow

Tags: mysql

does anyone know why joining to an empty temp table is very slow? When I have data in the temp table, the query runs in 0.2 seconds, but when the temp table is empty it takes 62 seconds to return an empty table. In my code, table1 is the empty table. Joining to an empty table should always result in an empty table, so why does this take so long?

```
drop table if exists table1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1  AS
(
select 
    username, channelnumber, LINKEDCHANNELDATA.ID
from
    voijavuusers.tbluserdata USERDATA
        left join
    voijavuusers.tbllinkedchanneldata LINKEDCHANNELDATA ON USERDATA.userguid = LINKEDCHANNELDATA.userguid
where
    USERDATA.username = 'tatatata'
);



select 
    CALLDATA.id, 
    CALLDATA.chanid,
    POPUPDATA.textboxfield1
from
    trmsmain.tblcalldata CALLDATA
        left join trmsmain.tblpopupdata POPUPDATA on CALLDATA.recordguid = POPUPDATA.recordguid 
        join
    (select 
        username,
        channelnumber,
        ID
    from
        table1
    where
        username = 'tatatata') LINKEDCHANNELS ON CALLDATA.chanid = LINKEDCHANNELS.channelnumber
order by CALLDATA.id desc limit 100000;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question about how the query is optimized -- the query plan.  I would suggest removing the subquery around `TABLE1`.  This should help the optimizer:

```
select cd.id, cd.chanid, pud.textboxfield1
from trmsmain.tblcalldata cd left join
     trmsmain.tblpopupdata pud
     on cd.recordguid = pud.recordguid join
     from table1 t1
     on cd.chanid = t1.channelnumber
where t1.username = 'Installer'
order by cd.id desc
limit 100000;
```

This doesn't guarantee that the optimizer will choose the right execution path, but it gives it more information to go on.  It shouldn't really make a difference, but I would also be inclined to put `table1` first in the `from` clause.

Comment: I removed the subquery around table1 but it made no difference

Comment: @Anton . . . I thought that would be an easy fix.  You'll need to look at the execution plans for the two queries.  Perhaps if you add an index on `table1(username, channelnumber)`, the query will use that table first.

Comment: Adding an index on table1(channelnumber) solved the issue with the join being slow when that table is empty, thank you.